# Mvc Action Link not using correct route

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have the following routes and typing them in the browser works fine and routes correctly, but if I use a Html.ActionLink, it tries using the DefaultStuff Route.

**Routes**

```
_routes.MapStuffRoute(
    "DefaultStuff",
    "stuff/{controller}/{id}",
    new { id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new[] { typeof(BaseApiController).Namespace });

_routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new[] { typeof(BaseController).Namespace });
```

**Page**

```
@Html.ActionLink("Job Queues", "Index", "Job") // generates http://localhost/stuff/job?action=Index
```

What am I missing to allow ActionLink to generate http://localhost/stuff/index. Reversing the routes the ActionLink is correct but the Stuff does not work.  Just a note, the StuffRoute sets the action name based on the information in the request.

Answer (score 1):

It seems as though you actually are trying to map the controller "Job" to stuff.  Currently your "DefaultStuff" route does not resolve an action, so it is putting it in as a query string value.

```
_routes.MapRoute(
"DefaultStuff",
"stuff/{action}/{id}",
new { controller="Job", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
new[] { typeof(BaseApiController).Namespace });
```

Comment: strictly speaking for an action to resolve to a route the route MUST correspond to an action, as your example does. In the OP's example `{action}` is replaced by `{controller}` which will cause the route resolver to fail

Comment: The Action is dynamically set in GetRouteData based on meta-data in the request.

Comment: Have a look at routedebugger. It might help you resolve such issues: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx